# How to do more condition in a ternary operator in my case

Tags: jsp, el

I want to wirte a test in my JSP using ternary operator my purpose is when the currentTab equal **'auther'** or **'about'** I want to use the class **auther** ,else no css class my question how I can do that using ternary operator if it's possible 
my code like this :

```
<body class="${CurrentTab eq 'author || about' ? 'author ' : '' }">
```

Comment: did you try `CurrentTab eq 'author' || CurrentTab eq 'about'` ?

Comment: No, I will try it now

Answer (score 3):

What about:

`<body class="${CurrentTab eq 'author' || CurrentTab eq 'about' ? 'auther' : '' }">`

Answer (score 3):

Your check is wrong!

```
CurrentTab eq 'author || about'
```

will compare the variable CurrentTab agains the string 'author || about'

You need to rewrite the check to compare the variable with each string, something like

```
CurrentTab eq 'author' || CurrentTab eq 'about' ? 'author' : ''
```